# How to iterate over an object - React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iteration, array.prototype.map

*WHAT I DO:*

- I fetched data from an api
- Then store the data into "**dataArray**"
- Then I loop over "**dataArray**" to populate "**quizzes**" with arrays of **questions**, **correct_answers** and **incorrect_answers**

I then want to iterate over "**quizzes**" to create instances of the component "**QuizPage**".

The problem is that "**quizzes**" is not an array so I can not use **.map()** over it and I don't know how to turn it into an array.

*QUESTION:*

Should I turn "**quizzes**" into an array (if so, how?) or is there another way to iterate over an object?

**APP.JS:**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import StartPage from './components/StartPage';
import QuizPage from './components/QuizPage';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

function App() {
  const [isQuiz, setIsQuiz] = useState(false)
  const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([])
  const [quizzes, setQuizzes] = useState(
    {
      question: [],
      correct_answer: [],
      incorrect_answers: [],
      id: nanoid()
    }
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&difficulty=medium&type=multiple')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setDataArray(data.results))
  }, [])
   

  function startQuiz() {
    const questionArray = []
    const correctAnswerArray = []
    const incorrectAnswerArray = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      questionArray.push(dataArray[i].question)
      correctAnswerArray.push(dataArray[i].correct_answer)
      incorrectAnswerArray.push(dataArray[i].incorrect_answers)
      
      setQuizzes({
        question: questionArray,
        correct_answer: correctAnswerArray,
        incorrect_answers: incorrectAnswerArray,
        id: nanoid()
      })
    }
    setIsQuiz(true)
  }

  const quizElements = quizzes.map(quiz => (
    <QuizPage
      key={quiz.id}
      question={quiz.question} 
      correctAnswer={quiz.correct_answer}
      incorrectAnswers={quiz.incorrect_answers}
    />
  ))


  return (
    <>
      <span className="top-shape"></span>
      {
        isQuiz ?
        {quizElements} :
        <StartPage startQuiz={startQuiz} />
      }
      <span className="bottom-shape"></span>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**QuizPage**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function QuizPage(props) {
   
  return (
    <>
      <div className="questions__container">
        <div className="question__wrapper">
          <h3>{props.question}</h3>
          <div className="answer__wrapper">
            <span>{props.correctAnswer}</span>
            {props.incorrectAnswers.map(ans => (
              <span>{ans}</span>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button>Check answers</button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to iterate over the **quizzes** object and return instances of the component "**QuizPage**"

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Object methods to loop your quizzes.

Example:

`Object.values(quizzes.question).map(questionItem => questionItem);`

Take a look at this link bellow maybe this can help.
https://flexiple.com/javascript/loop-through-object-javascript/